# best way to save/load Tensorflow model with large constant tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow model with a custom component that contains a large constant tensor which is used as a lookup table (via tf.gather).

The custom component is built from tf.Module but is not a Keras model.

While training, if I just save checkpoints using tf.train.Checkpoint, I don't retain the constant data tensor, and so don't have the data required to load the model later.

When saving the model using tf.saved_model.save(), everything works, but it takes too much space for the purpose of making many checkpoints.

I could save a single copy of the model initially and then checkpoints thereafter, and then piece the model together upon load, but it feels like there has to be a better way.

**Question**: What's the best way to package a constant tensor along with a model, which makes saving, loading, training, and inference run the smoothest, and which allows me to save checkpoints or weights that don't include the constant tensor?

I want to do things in the most Tensorflow-friendly way, because I've been bitten too many times by mysterious under-the-table Tensorflow dealings.